# How to delay the calling of a method until other code has completed first

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I want to delay the calling of a method until other code has completed first.

here's the action triggered by a button. the user scans a barcode. I would like that to have completed before I call this other method: `[self performSelector:@selector(otherMethod:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];`
 I tried using a delay but that's no good and unpredictable.

```
    - (IBAction) scanButtonTapped
{
    NSLog(@"TBD: scan barcode here...");

    // ADD: present a barcode reader that scans from the camera feed
    ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
    reader.readerDelegate = self;
    reader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMaskAll;

    ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;
    // TODO: (optional) additional reader configuration here

    // EXAMPLE: disable rarely used I2/5 to improve performance
    [scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25
                   config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                       to: 0];

    // present and release the controller
    [self presentModalViewController: reader
                            animated: YES];

    [self performSelector:@selector(otherMethod:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];


}
```

Comment: *What* do you want to have completed? The animation?

Comment: So you want to call that method after the `presentModalViewController:animated:` has finished (the user gets the `reader` controller presented? Or after the code has finished scanning? Check out `presentViewController:animated:completion` method of `UIViewController`.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe I just want to call otherMethod: after the barcode scan is complete.

Comment: Then you need to pass a block to the barcode scanning code.  Probably two blocks; one for success and one for failure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you need to use a delegate method

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info
{
   //call other method here
}
```

I am assuming you are using ZBar library

Answer (score 1):

You don't show your scanning code, but I think you need to pass it a block to call when the scanning is complete (successful or otherwise)

Imagine the scanning method looks like this:

```
- (void)scanBarCodeWithCompletionBlock:^(BOOL successfulScan)completionBlock {

    if (do the scan) {
        completionBlock(YES);
    } else {
        completionBlock(NO);
    }
}
```

You might want to pass the completion block to the scanner code via a property and have it passed about and called as necessary:

```
ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;
scanner.completionBlock = ^(BOOL successfulScan) {
    if (!successfulScan) {
         initiateMoaningSequence();
    }
};
```